# How to use FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId()?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to delete my FireBaseInstance with

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId()
```

I use a try/catch block but i get this error:

```
> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD W/System.err:     at
> com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source) W/System.err:     at
> com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.deleteInstanceId(Unknown
> Source) W/System.err:     at
> package.class.onCreate(DatenLadenActivity.java:57)
> W/System.err:     at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272) W/System.err:  
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
> W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
> W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
> W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
> W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
> W/System.err:     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) W/System.err:    
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: May I know why would you want to delete the instanceId?

Comment: A long storry... Somnething in my code was wrong and after what on MY Device FireBaseToken = null. I find the error and now on Emulators it works but on my device FireBaseToken still is null. So i want to reset it with FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId() but i dont know to use it. Thank you for answer :)

Comment: on my Device onTokenRefresh() don't start...

Comment: Dont forget to remove the token also. Because on relogin the new user will get the notifications from previous one: --- FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteToken(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(), INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`deleteInstanceId()` is a blocking call.  It cannot be called on the main thread.  If you only need to call it for development and testing, you can use a simple `Thread`:

```
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: Dont forget to remove the token also. Because on relogin the new user will get the notifications from previous one: --- FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteToken(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(), INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);